# My wireguard install has broken and I'm unable to fix it

Tags: terminal, network

Since I've installed Wireguard on my MacBook Air running MacOS Sierra it hasn't given me any major problems until now. I've been using [wgcf](https://github.com/ViRb3/wgcf) to generate the wireguard config file, but I don't think that has been the cause of my issues with wireguard. So, in the last day or two when I run `wg-quick up ~/wgcf/wireguard-profile.conf` it prints three lines and then hangs.

```
[#] wireguard-go utun
[+] Interface for wgcf-profile is utun1
[#] wg setconf utun1 /dev/fd/63
```

I've been trying to fix this in all different kinds of ways from using brew to uninstall and reinstall wireguard-tools and wireguard-go. I manually downloaded the latest version of go and wireguard-go and it still hangs like it did before. At this point I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to gdayhowyagoin on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/lje7y4/homebrew_wireguardgo_0020210212_ceased_working_on/) , wireguard-go version 0.0.20210212 is the culprit. If you're using brew, you can see how they downgraded it, but if youre using macports, you can follow this:

```
git clone --single-branch https://github.com/macports/macports-ports.git
cd macports-ports
git checkout e01555c11df59855b73fd540accc778a41145bf8
cd net/wireguard-go
sudo port install
```

I hope this clears your issue.